# java: package exists in another module: java.base intellij idea

Tags: java, gradle

Первый раз работаю с java, gradle и idea. У меня есть класс, который переопределяет базовый. Из-за этого мне бросает исключение:
[image: ошибка]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить данную проблему?

```
package java.io ;

import org.zenframework.z8.rmi.ObjectIO;

public class ObjectInputStream extends DataInputStream implements ObjectInput {

    public ObjectInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        super(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Object readObject() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        return ObjectIO.read(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: Удалите картинку и напишите код текстом.

Comment: @AntonNikolaev Сделано, исправил

Comment: мб поменять свой package на что-нибудь отличное от `java.io`.